# trigger lambda function from log write in cloudwatch log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've setup some aws cloudwatch agents to send logs to a cloudwatch log group and what I want to do now is get those into an elasticsearch cluster (on ec2). Ideally, what I want to do is write a lambda function that parses it and then sends it to elasticsearch, but also have the lambda function be triggered anytime a message is written to the log group. Is it possible to trigger lambda from a cloudwatch log group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subscribing AWS Lambda functions to CloudWatch Logs is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html). Also, streaming CloudWatch Logs to the AWS ElasticSearch service is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) you can find the documentation about adding a subscription to CloudWatch logs for Lambda.

For streaming to AWS ElasticSearch see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) (as mentioned before).